# .Where in LinQ not working correctly

Tags: linq, where-clause

I have **Documents** table and **Signs** table. **Document** record can be related with many records in **Signs** table.

Now, I want to get all records of **Documents** table when document ID appears in **Signs** table.

Here I get all documents:

```
var documents = (from c in context.documents select c);
```

Here I get all my signs and save into List:

```
var myDocuments = (from s in context.signs where s.UserId== id select s.ID).ToList();
```

This list contains collection on document ID.

And here, I'm trying to get all documents that exists in myDocuments list:

```
documents.Where(item => myDocuments.Contains(item.ID));
```

But, when I do *.ToList()* allways return all records (in database only exists one compatible record)

What is wrong in LinQ statement?

Comment: I can think of `s.UserId == id` failing to compare. Are you taking into account casing?

Comment: Do you save result of this query : `documents.Where(item => myDocuments.Contains(item.ID));` somewhere ?

Comment: Fabjan, I don't save the result of the query because I apply many filters later and finally I do .ToList()

Comment: Fabjan, It's true... I forgot to re asign value... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this statement doesn't modify the contents of documents, it merely returns the results (which you're not doing anything with):

```
documents.Where(item => myDocuments.Contains(item.ID));
```

documents is still the full list.

Change this line to something like:

```
var matchingIDDocs = documents.Where(item => myDocuments.Contains(item.ID));
```

And then use matchingIDDocs in place of "documents" later in your code.

Comment: Oh my God... I forgot documents = documents(...) Thanks!

Comment: Lol. It happens to all of us, don't worry. :)